# crear botones aleatorios

Tags: javascript

Necesito crear 3 botones en javascript de tal forma que cuando recargue la pagina se le asigne a cada boton un numero del 1 al 3 para que luego a esos botones llamen a otra funcion .No se me ocrre nada . Solo se hacer que un boton tenga de forma aleatoria un numero del 1 al 3 pero ya cuando son 3 y que no se repita en plan que el boton 1 si tiene el 1 no lo tengo el 2 ni el 3 y asi con los otros botones. 
Si alguien sabe como podria hacerlo o me explique un poco la logica que hay que seguir por que la verdad ando muy rallado

Comment: Hola, debes realizar tu pregunta en base al documento [ask]. No olvides realizar el [tour]-

Answer (score 1):

Espero que esto sea lo que buscas

```js
$(".btn").click(function(event) {
  function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;


  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
var arr = [1,2,3];
arr = shuffle(arr);

  $(".con-botones").html('<button type="button" name="button">'+arr[0]+'</button><button type="button" name="button">'+arr[1]+'</button><button type="button" name="button">'+arr[2]+'</button>') 
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" type="button" name="button">Botones Aleatorios</button>

<div class="con-botones">
      
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

Necesitas identificar cada boton, por ejemplo al boton uno le pones id="1" al dos id="2" al tres id="3". Ahora que tienes identificado los botones desde javascript le asignas el valor $("#1").value("el valor");

Espero haberte ayudado un saludo

Comment: Hola Domingo esto no responde a la pregunta, es un comentario, revisa por favor [answer]. Ayudanos a responder preguntas que sean realizadas en base al documento [ask].